# Do Painted Cowmanglers actually exist?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been getting into TF2 trading a lot more now, and I heard of something called a paintable Cow Mangler 5000.

Apparently, applying paint to the Cow Mangler would give it a unique color of fire.  Unfortuantely, I can't find any evidence online to support the existence of a painted Cow Mangler, let alone on the official TF2 Wiki.

Does such a thing exist? Is there evidence to support this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, there are [14 in existence](http://stats.tf/item/441/The_Cow_Mangler_5000). From [Official TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Cow_Mangler_5000):

> A small number of Cow Manglers were painted due to a glitch. All painted Cow Manglers were painted in Team colors, and these painted Cow Manglers had the team colors of the    model and projectiles changed to match the paint.

and

> October 14, 2011 [Item schema update]
>   -The Cow Mangler 5000 can no longer be painted.

Lots of glitched items like this exist.

---

I didn't think the paint actually did anything on these but apparently it does. Check out this demonstation on YouTube: